# Predictions with MLP - PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I did a MLP that worked well, but when i tried to do a regplot, i got a strange situation. That is my validate function (i wrote "rotulo", but its the same of "target"):

```
def validate(test_loader, MLP, epoch):
    
    MLP.eval()
    start = time.time()
    
    epoch_loss = []
    pred_list, rotulo_list = [], []
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in test_loader:

          dado, rotulo = batch

          #Forward
          pred = MLP(dado)
          loss = criterion(pred, rotulo)
          epoch_loss.append(loss.data)

          pred_list.append(pred.numpy())
          rotulo_list.append(rotulo.numpy())

    epoch_loss = np.asarray(epoch_loss)
    pred_list  = np.asarray(pred_list).ravel()
    rotulo_list  = np.asarray(rotulo_list).ravel()
    
    r2 = r2_score(pred_list, rotulo_list)
    
    end = time.time()
    if epoch%10 == 0:
        print('Epoch: {}, Loss: {:.4f} +/- {:.4f}, R2: {:.4f}, Time: {}'.format(epoch, epoch_loss.mean(), epoch_loss.std(), r2, end-start), flush=True)
        
    return pred_list, rotulo_list
```

And that is the way i saved my results:

```
train_losses = []
pred, rotulo = [], []

for epoch in range(args['num_epochs']+1): #+1 just to print the number 100 haha
    #Train
    train_losses.append(train(train_loader, MLP, epoch))
    
    #Validate
    pred.append(validate(test_loader, MLP, epoch)[0])
    rotulo.append(validate(test_loader, MLP, epoch)[1])
```

At the last epoch (101), got this result:

```
Epoch: 100, Loss: 0.0004 +/- 0.0001, R2: 0.9760, Time: 0.07705903053283691
```

Ok, then i wanted to plot my last results from my last epoch (160 preds):

```
pred = np.asarray(pred).ravel()
rotulo = np.asarray(rotulo).ravel()

data = pd.DataFrame({'Predict': pred, 'Target': rotulo})
data = data.iloc[-160:,:]
data.shape
r2_score(data['Target'], data['Predict'])
```

r2_score returned a value of -0.68, why that? If my last epoch was with a r2 of 0.976

Comment: Consider simplifying the question. Currently, it seems the question is about the r2 function, having nothing to do with the MLP. Could you reduce the example to *only* include the problematic code?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know exactly what's going on, so I gave to you all my steps that I considered important, since the construction of the validate function (this where is the return I'm using for calculate R2 for test data) to my iteration on epochs and print from last epoch